# Is my Georgia font messed up?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, x86

I've seen a growing trend in websites to use the "Georgia" font face, with serif.

This has been especially noticable for me since my computer decided to render Georgia like this (Twitter example)[image]

I checked this on a friend's computer and lo and behold, their Twitter looks TOTALLY different. I've been wondering why web designers have been using this nasty font on their sites, now I know (after inspecting elements in Firebug and thinking "Georgia didn't used to be this ugly..")

So my question is: Where can I get a replacement Georgia font file to install over this ugly mutated serif laden monstrosity that is offending my eyes?

Thanks SU!

:)

Comment: Have you checked "Fonts" (under "Appearance and Personalisation") in Control Panel? See what the Georgia font looks like in there.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that. It is in fact the Georgia font not be ing correct (I wondered when the creators changed it.. turns out they never did!)

Comment: Have you got another handy Win7 machine within reach that you can copy the font file from? Or maybe it could be pulled off of a Win7 install disk..

Comment: There are a lot of Vista computers, but I'm currently the only one with 7. I shall try to find it on the install disk :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just had a look around on my Win7 install disk and may have an answer:

On the Windows 7 install disk, if you locate the file `\sources\install.wim` and open that up (I used 7zip, which worked, not sure what else would) inside the archive you can search to `\1\Windows\Fonts\` and extract the `georgia.ttf` file (and the other versions such as bold and italic) directly.

Alternatively, you could try acquiring the file from another install of Windows 7.

You should then be able to reinstall the font.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Fantastic way to get that font back, worked a charm! :)